# Storing same key and different values in JavaScript array and Matching with a key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
     $(document).on('change', '.units', function () {
            var obj = $(this);
            unit_id = parseInt($(this).val());
            var item_array = [];
            var unit_array = [];
            var units = $(".units");
            var items = $(".items");

            $('#used_items tr').each(function () {
                $(this).find('.items').each(function () {
                    item_array.push($(this).val());
                });
                $(this).find('.units').each(function () {
                    unit_array.push($(this).val());
                });
            });
            var item_unit_associative_array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
                if (item_unit_associative_array[item_array[i]] == unit_array[i]) {
                    obj.val('');
                    return alert("Given Item Unit Already Selected");
                }
                else {
                    item_unit_associative_array[item_array[i]] = unit_array[i];
                }
            }
            console.log(item_unit_associative_array););
```

From **item_array** and **unit_array** I want to build new object like

> var item_unit_associative_array=[1:12, 1:13 ,1:14,2:10];

and finally want to check an object consists of **key:value**  like

> var test ={1:12}

is exists  or not in the **item_unit_associative_array**

Comment: The best way to build a key/value pair grouping in JavaScript is with an object `{1:12, 1:13 ,1:14,2:10}`

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible. Firstly what you have is syntactically wrong for an array, you need an object to store key/value pairs. However even then it wouldn't work as keys must be unique in an object. JS doesn't throw an error, but only the last value defined for the key will be stored. The closest thing you could do would be to store an array of objects, like this: `[{ 1: 12 },{ 1: 13 },{ 1: 14 },{ 2: 10 }]`, or an object which holds arrays: `{ 1: [12, 13, 14], 2: [10] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to nest two layers of *objects*. See the comments for the structure:

```js
var items = [ 1,  1,  1,  2];
var units = [12, 13, 14, 10];

// Create the object like so:
// { 
//   1: { 12: true, 13: true, 14: true },
//   2: { 10: true }
// }
var itemUnitAssociativeObject = {};
units.forEach(function(unitId, i) {
  var itemId = items[i];  
  if (!itemUnitAssociativeObject[itemId]) {
    itemUnitAssociativeObject[itemId] = {};
  }
  
  itemUnitAssociativeObject[itemId][unitId] = true;
});

console.log("1:13", test(1, 13));
console.log("1:10", test(1, 10));
console.log("2:10", test(2, 10));

function test(item, unit) {
   return !!(itemUnitAssociativeObject[item] &&
     itemUnitAssociativeObject[item][unit]);
}
```

If you don't like the nesting and the way it complicates your test, you can also "stringify" the item-unit id combination:

```js
var items = [ 1,  1,  1,  2];
var units = [12, 13, 14, 10];

// Create the object like so:
// { 
//   "1:12": true,
//   "1:13": true, // etc.
// }
var map = items.reduce(function(map, itemId, i) {
  var id = itemId + ":" + units[i];
  map[id] = true;
  return map;
}, {});

console.log("1:13", map["1:13"]);
console.log("1:10", map["1:10"]);
console.log("2:10", map["2:10"]);
```